# How to edit existing files in Document library

Tags: sharepoint-2010

It's odd but I don't find edit option to edit existing attachment in document library ,
[image]

**Updates::**

It can be done using "Open with explorer" option. However it's still not convincing solution because it won't work on non IE browsers.

Comment: it is not a programming question at all........

Comment: Where did I mention It's related to programming ? It's mostly interface based question..How do you replace existing file in document library ?

Comment: @Rishi stackoverflow is for programming quesitons. Read and understand the faq: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: @Marto: Sorry If I violated the rules. I had in mind I can post any tricky problems on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Yes but it should be related to programming only.

Comment: BTW, I've seen many posts here where people asking about books to learn X technologies and no one voted them negative.Any specific reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you do it problematically it is easy but i think you want to make it using wizard :)
well will answer it but an advice you can ask programming questions here only :)
 you can find an answer here :

[here](http://dotnetninja.wordpress.com/2009/01/12/how-to-open-sharepoint-documents-in-edit-mode-with-internet-explorer-6-and-windows-xp-without-regfix/)

and Do not get upset :) mark as answer if t helps

Comment: Eslam, To just replace existing file in existing document requires JS ? That's odd.. I don;t know why I never noticed this problem or I overlooked..How can I propose such solution where simple user interaction needed :(

Comment: you are working with Microsoft product you need to dig deep my friend :)

Comment: But there should be something user friendly I can't believe if it's missing..

Comment: Delet the document add it again with a new attachments :) easy squeeze :)